# jenkins git plugin using --local when authenticating with HTTPS

Tags: git, jenkins, https

We are just installing Jenkins on our servers and trying to get automatic deployment working for feature branches.

We are working with a local Gitlab installation on one of our own servers.

Git and Git Client plugin is installed on Jenkins. When a job is created using the HTTPS authentication, somehow the git plugin wants to set the global username for the server and uses the wrong command to do so.

We get the following error:

`Failed to connect to repository : Command "git config --local credential.username jenkins" returned status code 129:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unknown option 'local'
usage: git config [options]` (followed by all the various options)

The right option would be to use `--system`.

We already tried to specify the global username in the jenkins global config and also tried to put a gitconfig in the /etc/ directory on the server.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line git version may be too old for use with credentials.

The Jenkins git plugin [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) says

> a recent Git runtime is required (1.7.9 minimum, 1.8.x recommended)

Unfortunately, the CentOS 6 (and Red Hat 6) git version is too old (git version 1.7.1), as is the Debian 6 git version (git version 1.7.2.5). The CentOS 7 version and Debian 7 and Debian 8 versions of command line git are new enough to support credentials.

Instructions for installing a newer version of command line git on CentOS 6 are available on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/448814/yum-doesnt-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos6).

Another alternative is to enable the JGit implementation in the Jenkins git plugin and use the JGit implementation instead of the command line implementation. There are several use cases which the JGit implementation does not support (submodules, reference repositories, etc.), but if it meets your use case, switching the plugin to use JGit is simpler than installing a new version of command line git.